# Need to know about BOOTLOADER & REINSTALLTION

Tags: dual-boot

***Question 1:*** Recently I have installed Ubuntu 12.04LTS in one of my NTFS partition (converting it into ext4 JFS during Ubuntu installation). Now GRUB2 has became my default boot manager. 
Using easy bcd software I have changed my bootloader(GRUB) to windows boot manager. Now if I want to remove ubuntu & if I delete that partitions(my partitions: root,swap,home) using windows disk management , that holds ubuntu, then is there any possibilities to fail my pc to boot?

If I format the free space (after deleting partitions that i get) to NTFS again, is it will work smoothly with my windows 7?

***Question 2:*** If I want to reinstall ubuntu then what I have to do?

If I just show the mount points of my previous root,swap,home & format them & mount them as root,swap,home during new installation, is it the right process to reinstall???

Please Help...............

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove Ubuntu, use any partitioning tool to delete the Linux partitions. You can do this with Partition Magic on Windows, or use the Ubuntu installation disc. Ubuntu uses two partitions by default; a small swap partition and an Ext4 partition for everything else. Make sure you only remove partitions that are marked as type swap  Ext4 or ext3 - any NTFS or FAT partitions are for Windows. This removes the Ubuntu data from your computer but leaves the Grub boot-loader.

You this need to boot from your Windows CD to remove this. Select the rescue option and run fixmbr. This will restore the disk's boot code back to the Windows settings and your computer will now boot straight into Windows when you power up.

[Take a look at this site for more info](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=508927)

As far as reinstalling Ubuntu:

1. Download an Ubuntu LiveCD image (.iso) from Ubuntu Downloads and burn it to a disc.
2. Insert the LiveCD into your CD-ROM drive and reboot your PC.
3. Continue with the installation until you see: "How to partition the disk?".
4. If you have already partitioned the disk and left space for Ubuntu, install it to that and then follow the rest of the steps. Otherwise, choose automatic partition resizing its your best bet.
   or

Use the Windows Installer [Wubi](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer)